$f(z)=u+iv$ analytic in a region $R$ show that $\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}=|f'(z)|^2$
I want to show that if $f(z)=u+iv$ is analytic in a region $R$ then $\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}=|f'(z)|^2$
here is my attempt:
By definition,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}&=
\begin{vmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &  \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
  \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} &  \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{vmatrix} \\
&= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}- \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
\end{align}$$
Now I think I should use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to rewrite this as
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}- \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}= \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2$$
but I don't see why this is equal to $|f'(z)|^2$

$f’(z)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}-i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$.

@peek-a-boo That's what I was thinking, but Im trying to find proof of that in the book and I can't seem to find those identities. I was hoping someone might be able to explain why this is the case. The book Im using is just a Shaun's outline for self-study, so the text is pretty condensed. Not a lot of explanation,  and its been over a decade since I've taken a course in complex analysis

This is easy enough to (re)prove: you just take the difference quotient along the real axis (to get the first equality) and along the imaginary axis for the second equality. See here if you need more details.

@peek-a-boo Thank you for the reference!

The proof of the identity mentioned in the comments is extremely simple, really.
$$f'(z)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$$
right? And if this limit exists (i.e, if $f$ is differentiable at $z$), then it must be the same no matter by which path you take the limit. This means that $$f'(z)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(z+x)-f(z)}{x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z)=\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\frac{f(z+iy)-f(z)}{iy}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial (iy)}(z)=-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(z)$$
where $(x,y)=(Re(h),Im(h))$. In other words, $$f'(z)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(z)+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(z)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(z)-i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(z)$$
Squaring this hence gives $$|f'(z)|^2=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(z)\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(z)\right)^2 $$
If you sub in the CR equations you arrive at the desired equality in the form you wrote.
